# Ajax is not saving data in DataBase

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I am building a BlogApp and I am stuck on a Problem.

**What i am trying to do**

I am trying to access user's location via `JavaScript`and saving in the Model's instance in DataBase.

Accessing location is working fine. BUT saving is not working

**The Problem**

Location's city is not saving in DataBase. When i refresh the page then it doesn't save in DataBase.

models.py

```
     class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
        full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
        city = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
```

views.py

```
def func(request):
    city = request.GET.get('city')
    city.save()

    message = 'Updated'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

template (.html)

```
# Getting city name ( first javascript code ) through IP is working.

<script>

$.ajax({
  url: "https://geolocation-db.com/jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "callback",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(location) {
    $('#city').html(location.city);

  }
});

</script>



#This code is for send data to Django.

<script>

    $("city").change(function)(){
        const city = 'city';
        $.ajax({
            url ="{% url 'mains:func' %}",
            data = {
                'city':city,
            } ,
            success.function(data){
                console.log("Update");
            }
        });

    };

</script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div>City: <span id="city"></span></div>
```

I don't know where is the Problem.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: After writing `city = request.GET.get('city')` the variable `city` would then contain a string with whatever value is send in the get parameters (if the parameter is sent otherwise this would be `None`). On this you write `city.save()` which doesn't make sense (`str` doesn't even have a save attribute / method you would get an error there)

Comment: Then ,How can i save it ?

Comment: I believe you want to change the current users profile? You can get the profile by `profile = request.user.profile`

Comment: Yeah, What's the point of getting `request.user.profile` ? I mean whats the use of getting it ?

Comment: Since you want to update the profile instance obviously you need it... You would later write something like `profile.city = city` and then `profile.save()`...

Comment: I changed it. BUT it didn't save.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the profile instance belonging to the user which is referenced on the request.  (This is assuming the request is for a logged in user).

```
def func(request):
    city = request.GET.get('city')
    user = request.user
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    profile.city = city
    profile.save()
    message = 'Updated'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

Comment: This is still not saving. Do i need to add a `form` or `submit button` to save it in `db` ?

Comment: This will work.  Why do you think it hasn't saved?  You need to debug the code if it hasn't worked.  I'd suggest printing out the profile before you change it and afterwards to see if there is a change.

Comment: Because i checked it in `Admin`. City is still blank

Comment: That would suggest to me that city is an empty string in the view function and so the problem lies client side.  Again, you need to debug the code to see the error.

Comment: When i `inspect` it then it is showing `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'`. In line of `$("city").change(function)(){`

Comment: The change event listener you wrote does not have the right syntax.  You have forgotten to write a ")" after the "}".

Comment: I didn't find any mistakes. Can you spot me the right line ?

Comment: @Progam `$("city").change(function)(){` should be `$("city").change(function(){...})`